# Electrons only affected by electric field of EM wave misconception?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, polarization, absorption

When an EM wave is vertically polarised, and an aerial vertically aligned, a signal is received because it is in the correct alignment to absorb the wave that is vertically polarised (relative to the electric field oscillation)

The same would happen with a horizontally aligned aerial if the EM wave was horizontally polarised

[image]

However, if the aerial was aligned vertically and the wave polarised horizontally, no signal would be detected.

This implies that the electrons in the aerial are only affected by the electric field component of an EM wave and not the magnetic field component. Is this true? And how can this be explained intuitively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The force on electrons due to the electric component of the wave is so much larger than that due to the magnetic component, that the latter can be ignored for most practical engineering purposes. There are two reasons for this: the first is that in SI units the magnetic component ${\bf B}$ is $1/c$ times the electic field ${\bf E}$, but the principal one is that the electrons in the antenna are moving so slowly that the Lorentz force ${\bf v}\times {\bf B}$ is very small. They may be  oscillating rapidly  (MHz) but they do not move very far ---  and remember that even in a typical electric circuit  electrons are only moving on the order of  cm/sec.

Comment: So it's due to the small oscillations of electrons rather than the fact they have a very small charge that causes the magnetic component effect to be negligible?

Comment: Yes. The small charge does not matter. The ratio of electric force to magnetic force does not care about the electron charge as it cancels when you take the ratio of the two forces.

Comment: The practice of wireless transmission knows very well how to use the magnetic field component of EM radiation. See R.W. Birds answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the antennas shown in your sketch are receiving antennas, then the polarization which they respond to is determined by the direction of the conductors.  An alternative is a (circular) loop antenna. The plane of the loop aligns with the direction of propagation of the wave.  Then the changing flux of the magnetic field through the loop produces a voltage at a gap in the loop. (A horizontal loop responds to a vertical magnetic field.)

Comment: The EMF induced in the loop antenna is produced by   the time rate of change of the magnetic field i.e to $\rm curl {\bf E}$. In other words it is driven by the difference in the wave's ${\bf E}$ field between  the front and back part of the loop. The electrons are still being driven by the ${\bf E}$ component of the wave and not  by the ${\bf v}\times {\bf B}$ Lorentz force which is of order $|v_{\rm electron}|/c$ times smaller.